# How to call OpenSSL function from Python

Tags: python, cryptography, openssl

I'm working with EC crypt algorithm and I'm wondering how to use OpenSSL functions directly from Python.

For example, Ruby has that interface:

```
require 'openssl'
include OpenSSL
group = PKey::EC::Group.new('secp256k1')
bignum = BN.new('04fc9702847840...')
point = PKey::EC::Point.new(group, bignum)
```

Can I do that in Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check [PyOpenSSL](http://pythonhosted.org//pyOpenSSL/).

Quoting from their website:

> This module is a rather thin wrapper around (a subset of) the OpenSSL
>   library. With thin wrapper I mean that a lot of the object methods do
>   nothing more than calling a corresponding function in the OpenSSL
>   library.

Comment: Thanks, finally I decided on "cryptography" https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptography/0.2.2